# Main function stuck in a loop without it entering one

Tags: c, loops, program-entry-point

I have an assignment which is to make a basic implementation of the tail command in Linux, and it was going well, but when i run it it just goes to the next line and does nothing. Here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int counter;
    printf("program started");
    if(argc == 1)
    {
        printf("hello1");
        tailSTDIN();
    }
    else if(argc == 2)
    {
        printf("here");
        tailFile(argv[1]);
        printf("tailed");
    }
    else for(counter = 0; counter < argc; counter++)
    {
        printf("loop");
        if(argv[argc] == "-")
        {
            printTitle("standard input");
            tailSTDIN();
        }
        else
        {
            printTitle(argv[counter]);
            tailFile(argv[counter]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Ok, so the problem is that it just gets stuck, it doesn't even get to the first `printf()`, where it says `program started`, it just waits for something. And that's regardless of how many or what arguments I give it. 
If you believe you need the full code with the rest of the functions, I'll put it in, but the issue is that it never gets to the point of calling them.

Comment: how are you running your code. I mean command and the arguments.

Comment: It's not getting stuck, you're just never seeing what you print because standard out is line-buffered by default and you're not including any newlines in your messages to trigger a line flush.

Comment: Add `\n` to your printf calls (if you do output redirection then call `fflush(stdout);`).

Comment: Use a debugger. Or at least replace `"program started"` with `"program started\n"` to make sure the message appears (stdout may be buffered, newline forces flushing the buffer).

Comment: Also check `if(argv[argc] == "-")` - _"logical operation on address of string constant"_

Comment: yeah, the new lines were the problem, I'm on a linux terminal, using gcc, it works with newline characters in the printfs, i found the error

Comment: While grammatically allowed, sometthing like `else for ...` is bad formatting style, as that mixes conditional and iteration statements. You should only have `else if` on the same line (because C does not have a distinct `elif`keyword).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use stdout for output lines are buffered until whole buffer is filled or newline character is encountered.
Terminate you line with \n character:

```
printf("program started\n");
```

and you'll get your output.

Comment: Yep that's the problem, I'll mark as correct answer when it lets me :)